# What does the APN IP address does on a wireless router?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, bridging

i am bridging two wireless networks basically b'coz i wanna be able to use the printers connected with Eithernet cable on the router Huawei B683 while i am been connected to the second router Huawei B970b which have an internet connection accessible.

Now after my extensive googling and research i have found that the routers can be bridged and i wanna make the router B970b a wireless bridge to B683 so that all the users could be able to connect to it and hence the printer accessing issue would be resolved.

All i wanna know is can i Put the IP address of the B970b in the setting>dialup>APN>Ipaddress of the wireless router B683,will it be able to access the internet on the router B970 which is wirelessly bridged?

I have attached an image for better understanding and please note both these router have been provided by the same service provide.please follow the link for image

[network layout](http://mybroadband.co.za/vb/attachment.php?attachmentid=41482&d=1362394864)

Comment: URL is broken: Gives 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use the APN configuration to do what you want.  That is used if you have a 3G module installed.

The firmware on those devices don't appear to support any type of wireless bridging, and it doesn't look like it is supported by dd-wrt, a third party firmware.  You may find some other third party firmware that can help.

The best bet is to connect them via ethernet.